# Memory leak where CPython extension returns a 'PyList_New' instance to Python, which is never deallocated

Tags: memory-leaks, python-3.8, cpython

I've been trying to debug a memory leak for a few days and I'm running out of ideas.

High-level: I've written a CPython extension that allows querying against binary data files, and it returns the results as a Python list of objects.  Usage is similar to this psuedocode:

```
for config in configurations:
    s = Strategy(config)
    for date in alldates:
        data = extension.getData(date)
        # do analysis on 'data', capture/save statistics
```

I've used tracemalloc, memory_profiler, objgraph, sys.getrefcount, and gc.get_referrers to try to find the root cause, and these tools all point to this extension as source of an exorbitant  amount of memory (many gigs). For context, a single record in the binary file is 64 bytes, there are typically 390 records per day, so each `date` iteration is working with ~24K bytes. Now, there are many iterations happening (synchronously), but in each iteration the `data` is used as a local variable, so I expected each subsequent assignment to deallocate the previous object. The results from memory_profile suggest otherwise...

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurences   Line Contents
============================================================
    86     33.7 MiB     33.7 MiB           1    @profile
    87                                          def evaluate(self, date: int, filterConfidence: bool, limitToMaxPositions: bool, verbose: bool) -> None:
    92    112.7 MiB      0.0 MiB         101        for symbol in self.symbols:
    93    111.7 MiB      0.0 MiB         100            fromdate: int = TradingDays.getAdjacentDay(date, -(self.config.analysisPeriod - 1))
    94    111.7 MiB      0.0 MiB         100            throughdate: int = date
    95                                                  
    96    111.7 MiB      0.0 MiB         100            maxtime: int = self.config.maxTimeToGain
    97    111.7 MiB      0.0 MiB         100            target: float = self.config.profitTarget
    98    111.7 MiB      0.0 MiB         100            islong: bool = self.config.isLongStrategy
    99                                                      
   100    111.7 MiB      0.8 MiB         100            avgtime: Optional[int] = FileStore.getAverageTime(symbol, maxtime, target, islong, fromdate, throughdate, verbose)
   101    111.7 MiB      0.0 MiB         100            if avgtime is None:
   102    110.7 MiB      0.0 MiB          11                continue
   103                                                      
   104    112.7 MiB     78.3 MiB          89            weightedModel: WeightedModel = self.testAverageTimes(symbol, avgtime, fromdate, throughdate)
   105    112.7 MiB      0.0 MiB          89            if weightedModel is not None:
   106    112.7 MiB      0.0 MiB          88                self.watchlist.append(weightedModel)
   107    112.7 MiB      0.0 MiB          88                self.averageTimes[symbol] = avgtime
   108                                                      
   109    112.7 MiB      0.0 MiB           1        if verbose:
   110                                                  print('\nFull Evaluation Results')
   111                                                  print(self.getWatchlistTableString())
   112                                         
   113    112.7 MiB      0.0 MiB           1        self.watchlist.sort(key=WeightedModel.sortKey, reverse=True)
   114                                         
   115    112.7 MiB      0.0 MiB           1        if filterConfidence:
   116    112.7 MiB      0.0 MiB          91            self.watchlist = [ m for m in self.watchlist if m.getConfidence() >= self.config.winRate ]
   117                                                  
   118    112.7 MiB      0.0 MiB           1        if limitToMaxPositions:
   119                                                  self.watchlist = self.watchlist[:self.config.maxPositions]
   120                                         
   121    112.7 MiB      0.0 MiB           1        return
```

This is from the first iteration of the `evaluate` function (there are 30 iterations total).  Line 104 is where it seems to be accumulating memory. What's strange is that the `weightedModel` contains only basic stats about the data queried, and that data is stored in a loop-local variable. I can't figure out why the memory used is not cleaned up after each inner iteration.

I've tried to `del` the objects in question after an iteration completes, but it has no effect.  The refcount does seem high for the containing objects, and gc.get_referrers shows an object as referring to itself (?).

I'm happy to provide additional information/code, but I've tried so many things at this point a braindump would be a complete mess :)  I'm hoping someone with more experience might be able to help me focus my thought process.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Found it!  The leak was one layer deeper, where the extension function builds an instance of a Python object.

This was the leaky version:

```
PyObject* obj = PyObject_CallObject(PRICEBAR_CLASS_DEF, args);

PyObject_SetAttrString(obj, "id", PyLong_FromLong(bar->id));
# a bunch of other attrs...

return obj;
```

This is the fixed version:

```
PyObject* obj = PyObject_CallObject(PRICEBAR_CLASS_DEF, args);

PyObject* id = PyLong_FromLong(bar->id);
# others...

PyObject_SetAttrString(obj, "id", id);
# others...

Py_DECREF(id);
# others...

return obj;
```

For some reason I had it in my head that the PyLong_FromLong function did NOT increment the ref count of the resulting object, but this is apparently not true.  This is how I wound up with an extra reference count for every bar object that was created.